# When writing CSS, and you have multiple <P> tags that all need to be separate colors do you just keep writing separate <P> selectors or...?

Tags: html, css

When writing CSS, and you have multiple `<P>` tags that all need to be separate colors do you just keep writing separate `<P>` selectors or does there need to be a element/selector that separates them?

Comment: Would make different classes for them. `<p class="red">...</p>`

Answer (score 5):

You could use id such as: `<p id="p1"></p>`
or class such as: `<p class="p1"></p>`
on each element
or set the style from inside the tag such as `<p style="color:black;"></p>`. These are as far as I know the only ways you could do what you're hoping for.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use Inline CSS for every tag separately

please have a look at the below example.

```
<p style="color:red;">A red paragraph.</p>
<p style="color:green;">A green paragraph.</p>
```